# How to push data into an same object based on specific key in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, push

I have an jason result as below and I want to read from it and push to specific key as below
**JSON result**

```
[
{id:1,Name:"test",billNumber:"123"}
{id:2,Name:"test1",billNumber:"123"}
{id:3,Name:"test2",billNumber:"12345"}
{id:2,Name:"test3",billNumber:"12345"}
{id:3,Name:"test4",billNumber:"12334535"}
]
```

I want to have array list as below

```
{
"123":[{id:1,Name:"test",billNumber:"123"}, {id:2,Name:"test1",billNumber:"123"}],
"12345":[ {id:3,Name:"test2",billNumber:"12345"},{id:2,Name:"test3",billNumber:"12345"}],
"12334535":[{id:3,Name:"test4",billNumber:"12334535"}]
}
```

How to get the above list from the json result. Please do help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lodash to do that: just a regular `Array.prototype.reduce` will do the work. At each iteration, you simply check if the `billNumber` of the current item is in the object:

- if it is not (i.e. a new entry), then you assign an array with a single element
- if it is (i.e. the `billNumber` has been encountered before), then you simply push into the array

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  Name: "test",
  billNumber: "123"
}, {
  id: 2,
  Name: "test1",
  billNumber: "123"
}, {
  id: 3,
  Name: "test2",
  billNumber: "12345"
}, {
  id: 2,
  Name: "test3",
  billNumber: "12345"
}, {
  id: 3,
  Name: "test4",
  billNumber: "12334535"
}];

const transformedData = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.billNumber in acc) {
    acc[cur.billNumber].push(cur);
  } else {
    acc[cur.billNumber] = [cur];
  }

  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(transformedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupBy` from `lodash`:
`const result = groupBy(input, "billNumber")`
(`input` is your array)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `reduce` method.

```js
[
{id:1,Name:"test",billNumber:"123"},
{id:2,Name:"test1",billNumber:"123"},
{id:3,Name:"test2",billNumber:"12345"},
{id:2,Name:"test3",billNumber:"12345"},
{id:3,Name:"test4",billNumber:"12334535"},
].reduce((acc, value) => {
    if (!acc[value.billNumber]) {
        acc[value.billNumber] = [];
    }
    
    acc[value.billNumber].push(value);
    return acc;
}, {})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the mimic code You cann use and get help

```
var a = [{a:2},{a:3},{a:4}]

let b = {}
let c = 1
a.forEach(obj => {
  b[c] = [obj]
  c++
})
```

output will be

```
{ 
  1: [ { a: 2 } ],
  2: [ { a: 3 } ], 
  3: [ { a: 4 } ] 
}
```

Thanks I hope it will help !